# Cannot install/uninstall Drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm trying to install a modified version of the Rules HTTP Client module. But the problem is that I cannot install this because when I try to it tells me that "Rules HTTP Client" already installed.

So I tried to disable and uninstall the module first. I disabled it but then it is **not listed in the uninstall tab**.

I do not have access to the server on which the Drupal site is hosted so everything I do has to be through the admin dashboard on the site.

Previously I could just install a module and it would override the already installed module. Is there a way to uninstall this Rules HTTP Client module? And does anyone know why when disabled it does not show in the uninstall tab?

Comment: You need to check other module who as a dependencie with Rules HTTP Client module , those modules must be disabled before disable & uninstall  Rules HTTP Client

Comment: Checked all my modules. None of them are dependent on Rules HTTP Client. @F

Answer (score 0):

If the non-modified version doesn't appear in the uninstall tab, that's because it is already uninstalled or marked as uninstalled in database (you can check the `schema_version` in the *system* table, set to `-1` means uninstalled).

However, the previous sources are probably still there and the former .info file in this case need to be removed or at least commented out depending on how you can access the server.